# I cannot access ApplicationData.Current from Win32 unpackaged app?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

My code:

```
using System;
using Windows;

namespace SampleSynthesis {
  class Program {
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args) {

      var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
      Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream =
          await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("I want to listen to this text");

      using (var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream)) {
          await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
          Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer((uint)stream.Size);
          Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("audio.wav");
          await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
    }
  }
}
```

Compiled with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Speech.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.runtime.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\Windows.winmd","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" tts.cs
```

I am getting:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)
   at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_Current()
   at SampleSynthesis.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at SampleSynthesis.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Maybe exists another way to save wav? I know that I can use simpler `SetOutputToWaveFile()` but because of [cracks in the synthesized audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854279/windows-text-to-speech-subtle-cracks-in-the-wav-but-clear-sound-when-synthesize) I want to try some another method. I need to use Desktop Bridge? Instead of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` I tried `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder` and got the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current only applies to packaged apps that have an identity (UWP apps and Desktop Bridge apps). Unpackaged Win32 EXE don't have the concept of their own isolated app data.

It's not clear why you need to this here, or what you are trying to accomplish. This shouldn't have anything to do with cracks in the audio playback.

Comment: I just trying different methods to synthesize speech, because what else I can try. Thank you for the answer, I will try to use Desktop Bridge.